# How to create autocomplete with PHP PDO and MariaDB to return concatenate values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, autocomplete

I have a problem , i want to create with autocomplete to get back suggested information e.g A11 - some text, but i get back only e.g A11. I think that definetly problem is passing values from query in array and how to pass and structure array to display wanted data with autocomplete.
HTML

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <p><label>MKB dijagnoze: </label><input type='text' name='sifra_mkb' value='' class='auto'></p>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
$return_arr = array();

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=3306;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT sifra_mkb,naziv_mkb FROM i_dijagnoze WHERE sifra_mkb LIKE :term');
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $return_arr[] =  $row['sifra_mkb'].' '.$row['naziv_mkb'];
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Comment: `$stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));` should be `$stmt->execute(array(':term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));`. might be a typo?

Comment: @moni_dragu [it shouldn't be](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared).

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you. That's good to know. I never saw any example without the `:` in the documentation am checking:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1077